# How do I change the directory displayed in the RStudio file pane / navigator using code?

Tags: r, rstudio

I am writing an R package for a lab notebook. One function makes a new directoy with some Rmd files, opens the files with `file.edit`, and changes the current working directory to the new directory. It would be great if I could also change the "Files" pane of RStudio to display that new folder from the function's code. Is this possible? I have looked through the `rstudioapi` package. It does similar things (e.g. the `viewer` function), but I cant find a way to change the path in the file navigator pane.

Comment: Found this thread while writing the same question. Looks like there is no way to do it? Have you found anything?

Comment: @yuk: not yet. I will post it here if I do

Comment: @yuk: I am trying to locate your question without success. Can you please add a link so I can see If I can be of assistance to answer it.

Comment: @Toolbox: I didn't post the question, since I found this one. BTW your answer below is not what OP asks for. It's not about changing the working directory what you do with setwd, and not about setting default wd. But about changing the directory in Files panel in RStudio by a command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the following code,

```
rstudioapi::filesPaneNavigate(getwd())
```

Hope that works!

Comment: loving the answer to a 7 year old problem!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change one of your [Rprofile] files in your system. The Rprofile are loading at start of R in the following order:

- Rprofile.site (global)
- Rprofile (current directory)
- Rprofile (users home directory)

Add the following in your Rprofile (change to your path,though):

```
setwd('/your/path')
```

Logout/login of Rstudio and you should get the files pane of Rstudio to reflect what you stated in your Rprofile file.

Comment: Thanks, but a restart of Rstudio is not ideal for this application. I am looking for a R command that can be put into a package.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the working directory using `setwd()`. Inside of `setwd()` you need to provide the path to the folder you want to be your working directory, such as:

```
setwd("C:/Desktop")
```

I typically set the working directory every time I open R studio.

Comment: Thanks, but I was asking specifically about what folder is displayed in the "Files" pane in Rstudio, which can be different than the current working directory.